# ClientWithResponseHandler example Gives an ERROR?

Tags: httpclient, execute, http-get

I've tried hard to solve this and I couldn't. I'm trying to use httpClient 4.1.2 from apache. As logic I started with the example, the problem is that I'm having some strange error that I don't understand. This is the deal:

```
    package ClientWithResponseHandler;
    import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class Main {

public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/");

        System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

        // Create a response handler
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = **httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);**
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(responseBody);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

    } finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

}

The error is with "httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);" IT says that it cannot find the method execute(HttpGet,ResponseHandler)
The question shouldn't the example work? What am I doing wrong?! :S

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error too. I resolved it by adding the "httpcore-4.2.1.jar". Then it started complaining about the Class Def not found for logging. So I added "commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" and now I think it works fine. Both these files can be found along with "httpclient-4.2.1.jar".

Hope this helps.